# Trigger spark application with Apache Livy with parameters

Tags: apache-spark, livy

I am trying to trigger a spark application from Apache Livy however I cannot seem to get it to work. I am using latest version (0.5) and passing args based on the documentation https://livy.incubator.apache.org/examples/ however from the logs when the application runs, I am seeing that no arguments are taken into consideration.

```
curl http://livy:8998/batches -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "file": "hdfs path", 
    "className": "Main", 
    "name": "app",
    "args":[“arg1 value”, “arg2 value”]
}'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is file the path to your jar?

Comment: yes, and this works as I see logs in Livy that are tied with my applications. The only wierd thing that I see is that arguments are never taken into consideration...

Comment: Weird, what are the args and their types? Seems to be ok, here is an example https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/151164/how-to-submit-spark-application-through-livy-rest.html

Answer (score 2):

You used the wrong punctuation.

change

```
"args":[“arg1 value”, “arg2 value”]
```

to

```
"args":["arg1 value", "arg2 value"]
```